# Trying to generate id and data-bs-target dynamically but not working

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5, angular10

```
<ul> 
     <li data-info="Amount in (₹)">{{depositeAmt}}</li>
     <li data-info="Status">
        <button class="statusbtn Process"  data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample1" >{{status}}</button>
     </li>
</ul>
<div class="newClass collapse" id="collapseExample1{{i}}">
```

where i is defined in ts file as i:number=1;

Comment: tried this way also:

Comment: <li data-info="Status"><button class="statusbtn Process"  data-bs-toggle="collapse [attr.data-target]="'#collapseExample'+{{i}}" >{{record.status}}</button></li>
                                   
 <div class="trasactionboxshow  collapse"  id={{'collapseExample'+i}}">

Answer (score 11):

To add an attribute using an expresion or variable you can use

```
[attr.name-of-attribute]="expresion"
```

e.g.

```
[attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapseExample'+i"
```

But I don't know if you can use with bootstrap to create a collapse

Comment: Hi Eliseo @eliseo , can you please look into this question if possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475845/is-there-any-way-to-retain-the-state-of-multiple-expandable-mat-grid-after-refre  ? TIA .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very similar to the answer provided in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72753325/how-to-set-a-dynamic-id-for-boostrap-modal-data-bs-target/73651921#73651921):

Please, see it and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: It would be better to either expand your answer so it works without the link, or consider marking the question as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, but the solution presented here didn't work for my scenario.

In my case it only worked that way.

`<button attr.data-bs-target="#id-here-{{ obj.attribute}}">Click</button>`

`<div id="id-here-{{ obk.attribute }}">Content ...</div>`