# How to set a dynamic id for Boostrap Modal data-bs-target?

Tags: html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I need to set as a dynamic id for the Boostrap modal and refer it.

```
<div class="modal"  id="questionEdit">
</div >
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#questionEdit">Edit Question</button>
```

I have tried following way

```
<div class="modal"  th:id= "${question.question_id}  + 'question_editModal' ">
</div >
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#${question.question_id}  + 'question_editModal'">Edit Question</button>
```

But this is not working. Can anyone hel pme to fix this?

Comment: Is it just me and you who had this kind of problem? I have a very similar one when the user should provide an answer to a list of questions. Each answer opens a modal, which would have a unique id, corresponding to the question's id.

Comment: @Yuriy I think so, bro! Are you developing a question and answer forum? I have used a bootstrap model for submitting questions. It is working perfectly, but I also need to open a bootstrap model with a dynamic thymleaf id for editing questions.  I think it is similar to your case. Are you using Java in the backend?

Comment: I just post my comment and after that, I found out how to fix the problem. I just want people to know because many times I am searching and could not find similar problems tha that I had. So, if it helps even one developer, it is worth it. My back end is Ruby on Rails and I am using React on the Front end with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out. At least in my case, it is working. So for your code, it should be something like this:

```
<div class="modal"  th:id= {`question_editModal${question.question_id}`}>
</div >
```

and:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`#question_editModal${question.question_id}`}>Edit Question</button>
```

Please, let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: I changed my code as  <div class="modal"  th:id={`question_editModal${question.question_id}`}>. But an error occured."org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "{`question_editModal${question.question_id}`}" " How to fix this issue?

Comment: There are Backticks ``, which I do not see in your code!

Comment: I copied and paste your code. Backticks are disappeared after comment submission. Can you please show your dynamic id and data-bs-target id?

Comment: In this fragment, I am using "answerModalLabel": <div className="modal fade" id={`answerModal${id}`} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby={`answerModalLabel${id}`} aria-hidden="true">
 and in the next you can see also "answerModal" in the parent component: { this.state.answer == null ?
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary position-relative" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`#answerModal${this.state.id}`} onClick={this.provideAnAnswer}>
                Provide an answer
              </button>
            }